# In-page anchor not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, anchor

I'm having issues with my in-page anchor tag. When you click the down arrow, `<a href="#two">`, it should scroll down to the `<div id="two">`. It's working just fine in Chrome & Safari, but Firefox doesn't register the arrow as a link at all.

I've tried changing the `<div>` to an `<a>` tag, replacing `<div id="two">` with `<a name="two">`, I can't seem to get anything to work for me in Firefox.

Thoughts?

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}


* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}


.arrow {
    color: black;
    font-size: 5em;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}

.arrow:hover {
    color: lightgray;
}

.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>
<button class="button">
  <a href="#two">
    <span class="fontawesome-angle-down arrow"></span>
  </a>
</button>
</div>

<div id="two" class="section">
  <article class="fade relative">
    <div id="name">
      <a href="#">
        <a href="https://iamtrask.github.io/" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="I Am Trask" />
        </a>
      </a>
      <h2 class="absolute-text art-title">I AM TRASK</h2>
      <div id="hidden" class="absolute-text">
        <p>• bullet 1<br>• bullet 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove that `<button>` tag, it makes no sense in this context, since you don't want a button, but an icon. in the following snippet I assigned your `.button` class to the parent div and removed the button element itself.

I also added this to get rid of the underline below the arrow link:

```
.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}


* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}


.arrow {
    color: black;
    font-size: 5em;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}

.arrow:hover {
    color: lightgray;
}

.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 250px;
}
.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#two {
  height: 800px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="button">
  <a href="#two">
    <span class="fontawesome-angle-down arrow"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="two" class="section">
  <article class="fade relative">
    <div id="name">
      <a href="#">
        <a href="https://iamtrask.github.io/" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="I Am Trask" />
        </a>
      </a>
      <h2 class="absolute-text art-title">I AM TRASK</h2>
      <div id="hidden" class="absolute-text">
        <p>• bullet 1<br>• bullet 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: You rule. That fixed it. Thanks!